# usage of set_wakeup_fd() in signal module

Tags: python

I have read the docs but can't understand usage of this function, can someone give me a example? thanks

> Set the wakeup fd to fd. When a signal is received, a '\0' byte is written to the fd. This can be **used by a library to wakeup a poll or select call**, allowing the signal to be fully processed.
>
> The old wakeup fd is returned (or -1 if file descriptor wakeup was not enabled). If fd is -1, file descriptor wakeup is disabled. If not -1, fd must be non-blocking. It is up to the library to remove any bytes from fd before calling poll or select again.
>
> When threads are enabled, this function can only be called from the main thread; attempting to call it from other threads will cause a ValueError exception to be raised.

Comment: Where exactly did you read that? The [documentation I found](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.set_wakeup_fd) has a different wording.

Comment: Are you asking what the *purpose* of this function is, or do you understand its purpose, but not how it is used correctly?

Comment: I have read in https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.set_wakeup_fd,

Comment: I don't know purpose of this function, can you give me a example?

Comment: Apparently the behaviour of the function has changed slightly in Python 3, and the documentation adds more explanation. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain it right now.

Comment: I don't know how it is used to wake up a select call

Comment: Could you include some example code in your question that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here are some code examples: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/14555/signal.set_wakeup_fd